# Why was Ulises' life threatened after the gang shooting?

Tags: plot-explanation, i-am-no-longer-here

In the film *I Am No Longer Here*, Ulises is forced to leave his city for New York because he is afraid he will be killed by a local gang if he stays. However, it is unclear to me who threatens his life and why.

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia's plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_No_Longer_Here#Plot)? It seems to explain this fairly clearly.

Comment: You're right, I should have checked.